# Compressed keys default for brainwallet?

Tags: address, public-key, brain-wallet

I'm somewhat confused re compressed addresses...
Assuming I were to make a brainwallet using "correct horse battery staple" as my passphrase gives [1JwSSubhmg6iPtRjtyqhUYYH7bZg3Lfy1T](https://blockchain.info/address/1JwSSubhmg6iPtRjtyqhUYYH7bZg3Lfy1T) (uncompressed pubkey) & [1C7zdTfnkzmr13HfA2vNm5SJYRK6nEKyq8](https://blockchain.info/address/1C7zdTfnkzmr13HfA2vNm5SJYRK6nEKyq8) (compressed pubkey).
Both show evidence of being plundered by bots "watching" easy targets like these.
But which is the **standard**? ie Is uncompressed or compressed key the preferred format? A better way to phrase this is...
***"What format of key will be used going forward; compressed, uncompressed, or a combination?"***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compressed keys are better for use.
Because the redeem transaction size will be smaller, so one can save a fee.
Unfortunately, the original design of brainwallets created uncompressed keys. 
And now this setting is default.
It is too late to change the default behavior of this.
Let us say that "uncompressed" keys are standard de-facto.